# Binary search for tuples

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make a code that uses binary search for comparing a tuple with 2 values in it (name, last name)

```
names = [('Josh', 'Belluga'), ('Daisy', 'Fox'), ('Elin', 'Grosefield'), ('Dina', 'Ram'), ('Mike', 'Levinsan')]
```

the binary search code get that sorted list

```
def find_name(lst,name,low,high):
    if name == lst[high]:
        return high
    if name == lst[low]:
        return low
    if low >= high:
        return None
    middle = (low + high) / 2
    if lst[middle] == name:
        return middle
    **if lst[middle] > name:**
        return find_name(lst, name, low, middle)

    return find_name(lst, name, middle + 1,high)
```

for some reason, the part where I put the ** is always giving me the value true and because of that it never gets to search the higher parts of the list

Comment: Looks like `lst` is a list of `tuple`s. So `name` is a tuple. My guess is that the comparison is not working the way you think it is. I would try an example of the `>` and `<` operators on some tuples to see if the result is what you expect.

Comment: I ran you code on the example you provided, and it seems to work for me. Can you give an example where there's an error and what the expected output should be?

Comment: try to run it with the name = ('Elin', 'Grosefield'), it will give you None instead of the index

Comment: I ran `find_name(names, ('Elin', 'Grosefield'), low=0, high=len(names)-1)` and I got the number `2`, which is correct.

Comment: i checked it again and it happens when you run it on a bigger list, I will fix the code in the question try to run it on ('Dina', 'Ram') now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For binary search to work, your items need to be sorted properly.

In your version of the algorithm, you're doing direct `tuple` comparisons. That means the `tuple`s need to be sorted according to their comparison rules, i.e. first by the first element and—when the result of that is inconclusive—then by the second.

If you try your algorithm on this list, you'd see it work:

```
>>> list(sorted(names))
[('Daisy', 'Fox'), ('Dina', 'Ram'), ('Elin', 'Grosefield'), ('Josh', 'Belluga'), ('Mike', 'Levinsan')]
```

If you want to have the list sorted by last name, you first need put `('Mike', 'Levinsan')` in the right position. The result should be:

```
>>> list(sorted(names, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
[('Josh', 'Belluga'), ('Daisy', 'Fox'), ('Elin', 'Grosefield'), ('Mike', 'Levinsan'), ('Dina', 'Ram')]
```

Next, you need to change this line in your algorithm:

```
if lst[middle] > name:
```

to something like:

```
if (lst[middle][1], lst[middle][0]) > (name[1], name[0]):
```

so that you're comparing last names before names.